# set cell value from combobox vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

lookup by combobox and return 2nd column value works

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim x As Variant   
    x = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    myLookupValue = x
    Set myTableArray = Worksheets("material pricing").Range("matprice")
    myVLookupResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, myTableArray.Value, 2, False)
    MsgBox "Product " & x & " is " & Format(myVLookupResult, "#,##0")
    End Sub
```

change returned value = textbox14 gives an error

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Worksheets("material pricing").Range(myVLookupResult).Value = TextBox14.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What error are you getting, specifically? what is the value of `myVLookupResult`, and where is this variable declared, and more importantly, where is it assigned? Is `Option Explicit` specified at the top of the module?

Comment: varible is declared in `UserForm_Initialize()` as `Long` and no `Option Explicit` is not being used.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify that very important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myVLookupResult` is local to the `UserForm_Initialize()` procedure: it's defined there, exists there, and nowhere else. Once execution leaves the procedure's scope, the local variable ceases to exist: it's gone, and its value is inaccessible.

`Option Explicit` not being specified is not helping either.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim x As Variant   
    x = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    myLookupValue = x
    Set myTableArray = Worksheets("material pricing").Range("matprice")
    myVLookupResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, myTableArray.Value, 2, False)
```

Here `myVLookupResult` isn't the same variable you had in `UserForm_Initialize`: it's another local variable, local to the `ComboBox1_Change` procedure, except it's not declared - and the only way this is legal, is because `Option Explicit` being unspecified, is allowing it.

So a local variable named `myVLookupResult` is created on-the-fly in that procedure, and again dies when `End Sub` is encountered.

So when the `CommandButton4_Click` handler runs:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Worksheets("material pricing").Range(myVLookupResult).Value = TextBox14.Value
End Sub
```

`myVLookupResult` is yet another new local variable, this time local to the `CommandButton4_Click` procedure - except it has no value, so it's `Variant/Empty`, and that isn't a valid `Range` address, so the error you're getting is run-time error 1004: `Worksheet.Range(Empty)` isn't legal.

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module (and EVERY module you ever write!). That will prevent VBA from successfully compiling code that doesn't declare its variables (which prevents accidental typos!).

Then, move the declaration of `myVLookupResult` to module-level, like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private myVLookupResult As Long
```

Now, that fixes the `Variant/Empty` problem... but doesn't make the `Range` call any more legal.

Say the variable contains `42`.

```
Worksheets("material pricing").Range(42).Value = TextBox14.Value
```

I'm not sure what specific cell you're trying to assign here, but that `42` needs to be a valid cell reference. Say you want to write to cell `F42`, you could concatenate the `42` with `"F"`, like this:

```
Worksheets("material pricing").Range("F" & myVLookupResult).Value = TextBox14.Value
```

And that should work.